# How can I copy a file from DocumentPicker to my own application?

Tags: swiftui, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm asking the user to select an image or file in the "Folder" application in iPhone with DocumentPicker. How can I transfer this selected file or image to my own application?

I got this error: *Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found*

[image]

**Sheet:**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isOpenDocumentPicker, onDismiss: {
            self.isOpenDocumentPicker = false
        }, content: {
            DocumentPicker(fileContent: $fileContent)
        })
```

**DocumentPicker:**

```
struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var fileContent: String
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPickerCoordinator {
        return DocumentPickerCoordinator(fileContent: $fileContent)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController
        controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.text, .pdf, .folder, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .exe, .data], asCopy: true)
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
        
    }
}

class DocumentPickerCoordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @Binding var fileContent: String
    
    init(fileContent: Binding<String>) {
        _fileContent = fileContent
    }
    
    
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        let fileURL = urls[0]
        do {
            fileContent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch let error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you meant by "to my own application"? Inside bundle? - no. Inside sandbox - just use FileManager with received URL to copy.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories#3331289) you have to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` before accessing a files content.

In your case I'd update the `documentPicker()` function as follows:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    let fileURL = urls[0]

    guard fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
        // Handle denied access
        return
    }
    defer { fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

    do {
        fileContent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir but.. 
I put breakpoint but its not working.. 
I got this error. 

"Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found"